# Matching query does not exist issue Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am trying to create a web app that has a Like button option for the Post. Everything works fine but when I click on the Like button it shows DoesNotExist error.

This is the model part of the code:

```
class Like(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(Yatru, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, max_length=8)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}-{self.location}-{self.value}"
```

This is the views:

```
def like_unlike(request):
    user = request.user 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        location_id = request.POST.get('location_id')
        location_obj = Post.objects.get(id=location_id)
        profile = Yatru.objects.get(user=user)

        if profile in location_obj.liked.all():
            location_obj.liked.remove(profile)
        else:
            location_obj.liked.add(profile)
        
        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=profile, location_id=location_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value=='Like':
                like.value='Unlike'
            else:
                like.value='Like'
            
            location_obj.save()
            like.save()
    return redirect('posts:post_views')
```

When I try to load the page it shows this error:

> DoesNotExist at /posts/liked

Comment: Check what you are getting in `location_id` . This is the reason the query not able to find the object in DB and hence coming DoesNotExist error. If the correct id is received then convert it to `int` before passing to query.

Comment: I tried printing location_id and it shows None.

Comment: So the issue is in your template, as on submitting form your are not getting location_id in the request. Debug it.